# Opening window + view from an other view controller

Tags: swift, macos, view, window, viewcontroller

I've got a ViewControllerOne. ViewControllerOne is connected via Ctrl-Drag (in storyboard) to a menu-button mBtn (which means I don't know how it is implemented programmatically).

Clicking on this mBtn, a ViewOne appears (present modal). This ViewOne is bound to ViewControllerOne. ViewOne has a button btnOne.

Clicking on btnOne I want ViewOne to be dismissed and ViewTwo to be shown. ViewTwo belongs to ViewControllerTwo and to WindowControllerTwo.

The WindowControllerTwo-ViewControllerTwo-binding is the standard case as created on a new project.

I have the following code in the IBAction for button btnOne in ViewControllerOne:

```
@IBAction func onbtnOnePressed(sender: AnyObject){

        let m_WindowControllerTwo = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("WindowControllerTwo")) as! NSWindowController // I have no custom class for the window controller as I don't really know what I can use it for ... 

        let m_ViewTwo = WindowControllerTwo.contentViewController as! ViewControllerTwo // my custom class for ViewTwo

        m_ViewTwo.attributeIWantToPassToThisView = self.x // an attribute I want to pass from view a to view b

        m_WindowControllerTwo.contentViewController = m_ViewTwo // passing the attribute from a to b

        m_WindowControllerTwo.showWindow(self) // this does not work

        self.dismiss(nil)  // see NOTE
    }
```

This code actually does not work. On debugging it step by step, I'm seeing the window/view flickering but not appearing...

NOTE: I could connect the button btnOne with a ctrl-drag to ViewControllerTwo. This works. But then the current ViewOne does not get dismissed!

Question: What am I doing wrong here? In iOS swift this also works. I don't quite get the WindowController stuff, so I'll need your advice on this.

Comment: Your question is very confusing due to the naming that you've mentioned. Instead of doing that use the names of viewControllers itself.

Comment: Changed it ... now more clear I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this: `m_WindowControllerTwo.showWindow(self)`

use:

```
let application = NSApplication.shared()
application.runModal(for: wordCountWindow) //this will present WindowControllerTwo modally.
```

then to close your present controller add this line: `PresentWindowControllerName.close()`

Comment: I guess you did not understand my question. Where do you open a new window in your example? Furthermore, 'dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)' is iOS-swift and I am using macOS-swift...

Comment: nice, that helped a lot! Could you think of a way to pass a value from the first view controller to the second one (WindowControllerTwo)?